# Using space created with \hangafter

Tags: positioning, plain-tex

In Plain TeX, I'd like to put a box or a picture (with epsf) in the space created with \hangafter=-3 \hangindent=-3cm (i.e. upper-right corner)

I got the following MWE, but I'd like to move around the box a little bit

MWE:

```
\def\mybox{\hbox to 20mm{\vrule height 12mm depth 0cm\hfill\vrule}}
\def\blah{1) Due masse, di 5 kg e 3 kg, sono collegate da un'asta lunga 1m,
di massa trascurabile, e sono sospese, in equilibrio, con un filo che passa
per il baricentro.
Il sistema ruota orizzontalmente compiendo 1 giro al minuto,
calcolare il momento d'inerzia del sistema rispetto il centro di rotazione,
il suo momento angolare, la sua energia cinetica.}

\hangafter=-3\hangindent=-3cm
\noindent
\vadjust{\moveright\hsize\llap{\vbox to 0pt{\kern-10pt\mybox}}}
\blah
\par
\vskip3mm
\bye
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I added `%` to avoid getting a spurious space as shown before `1)` in your image, and `\vss` so the zero sized box does not make overfull box warnings.

The two kerns can then be set to arbitrary values to move the box horizontally and vertically without disturbing the rest of the paragraph.

```
\def\mybox{\hbox to 20mm{\vrule height 12mm depth 0cm\hfill\vrule}}
\def\blah{1) Due masse, di 5 kg e 3 kg, sono collegate da un'asta lunga 1m,
di massa trascurabile, e sono sospese, in equilibrio, con un filo che passa
per il baricentro.
Il sistema ruota orizzontalmente compiendo 1 giro al minuto,
calcolare il momento d'inerzia del sistema rispetto il centro di rotazione,
il suo momento angolare, la sua energia cinetica.}

\hangafter=-3\hangindent=-3cm
\noindent
\vadjust{\moveright\hsize\llap{\vbox to 0pt{\kern-10pt\mybox\vss}\kern0pt}}%%%
\blah\blah

\bigskip

\hangafter=-3\hangindent=-3cm
\noindent
\vadjust{\moveright\hsize\llap{\vbox to 0pt{\kern-20pt\mybox\vss}\kern40pt}}%%%
\blah\blah

\bye
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: use the `plain TeX` macro package `insbox`, and its command `\InsertBoxR{no of full width lines}{box inserted}[optional number]`.

The optional number is a corrective term, the number of supplementary lines to be shortened, in case TeX has erroneously calculated the number of shorter lines necessary for the box insertion.

There also exists a `\InsertBoxL` and a `\InsertBoxC` comaands.

Comment: `insbox` is what I needed, learnig material